# How should an RSA Public Key be exposed over HTTP?

Tags: java, http, rsa, public-key-encryption

We have a requirement to expose an RSA Public Key as an HTTP resource - so
http://myhost.com/publickeys/akeyid
returns a public key.

I would like to return it with a correct Internet Media Type. What should that be? I confess I find the crypto RFCs fairly impenetrable.

And as a bonus, how do I translate easily from and to that format using the java.security standard libraries?

(It's easy enough to go from and to a SubjectPublicKeyInfo byte array as defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.1 using java.security.RSAPublicKey.getEncoded() to serialize to bytes and a java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec to deserialize those same bytes; but I can't find a registered media type for that format which suggests to me that I should be using some other format (an x.509 Certificate?). But then I struggle to work out how to do the translation.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One alternative would be to encode the PKCS#1 format RSA public key as a PEM file, and then use the MIME type:

```
   "application/x-pem-file"
```

References:

- http://www.cryptosys.net/pki/rsakeyformats.html
- http://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mime.html

Note: "application/x-pem-file" is not registered ... obviously! ... but is referenced in a number of catalogues of "file types".

---

You probably ought to deliver the key over HTTPS ...

Comment: application/x-pem-file looks like the closest we are going to get, thanks. Shame there isn't a media type for a Binary DER-encoded public key, as that would be the ideal for us. I guess since the PEM one is not a standard either there's nothing stopping us defining our own...

Comment: ... or you could use application/octet-stream